# "Gain/acquire/gather/get experience"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, nouns, collocation

According to my Longman dictionary, *gain experience* and *get experience* seem to mean the same:

> **gain/get** experience: The programme enables pupils to gain some experience of the world of work.

But I have also found *gather experience* and *acquire experience* ([source](http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/erfahrungen-sammeln)):

> - We now have to **gather** experience.
> - These projects will set their imagination in motion, and will help  them **acquire** useful experience.

How do these versions with *gain*, *get*, *acquire* and *gather* differ? I am also interested if they mean the same but sound slightly different to native speakers.

Answer (score 5):

*Gain* adds to *get* the notion of something profitable or desirable (which is why we can *get* sick, but we don't *gain* sickness.) So, saying that an internship will help you *gain* experience implies that the experience you get might be useful down the road, such as on a resumé for a future job.

Using *gather* or *acquire* in conjunction with *experience* seems more suitable for corporate applications than personal endeavors. In other words, I can imagine a manager saying something like, *“We need to acquire more experience in database applications before we put in a bid for projects like that.”* However, if someone is talking about personal experience, (as in *“I want to go to a third world country before starting college; I think I would gain some valuable experience”*), then I wouldn't recommend substituting *gather* or *acquire* in that context.

Answer (score 1):

*acquire* and *get* are a formal and an informal version of the word for obtaining some specific amount of experience - the amount that makes a difference between "inexperienced" and "experienced". You don't get experience as a shopkeeper over one day of work, you get it after at least a couple weeks.

*gain* and *gather* are passive (you do your work and experience comes by itself) and active (you seek out opportunities to gain more experience) of the process.

You *gain* some experience over a day of work putting plaster on the walls. You *get* the experience of skilled plasterer over the course of three months. But you will *gather* the experience of a builder only if you quit plastering and seek out other occupations by changing specializations and *getting* experience in each of them - learn carpentry, masonry, basics of technical drawing reading, and a bunch of others that comprise the broad definition of a builder.

The borders aren't firmly defined, and people will often "get a little experience" (gain), or "gather experiences of others" (poll), and generally all these can be used more or less interchangeably - what I outlined is just a kind of "hunch" where which fits.

Answer (score 0):

To me, they all mean the same thing. All that's different is the style and level of pretension.

> I'd say "The program gives pupils some experience of the world of work": no pretension.

The next sentence comes from "Gather ye rosebuds while ye may // Old time she is a flying". Just a metaphor.

> I'd say "We need experience": no pretension.

"Acquire" is three syllables long, the most pretentious option, and related to the notions of language acquisition (an involuntary process in young children) and business predation (one business buying another).

> I'd say "These projects will set their imagination in motion, and will give them useful experience": no pretension.